# SharedAccessAuthorizationRule and GetQueues are crossing "Queue Boundaries"

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have Service Bus 1.1.  On Premise.  But that part may not matter.

I've setup SharedAccess security for my Queues.  Each queue is assigned a SharedAccessKey

Code looks something like this:

```
/* \packages\WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.2.1.4.0\lib\net40-full\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll */
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbcsb = /* not shown */;
NamespaceManager nsm = new NamespaceManager(sbcsb.GetAbsoluteManagementEndpoints(), tp);                        
QueueDescription currentQueueDescription = new QueueDescription("MyQueueOne");
currentQueueDescription.SupportOrdering = false;
currentQueueDescription.LockDuration = "1000";

ICollection<AccessRights> accessRightsCollection = new List<AccessRights> { AccessRights.Listen, AccessRights.Manage, AccessRights.Send };

string currentRandomKeyName = "MyListenManageSendKeyName" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
string currentRandomKeyValue = SharedAccessAuthorizationRule.GenerateRandomKey();                       

currentQueueDescription.Authorization.Add(new SharedAccessAuthorizationRule(currentRandomKeyName, currentRandomKeyValue, accessRightsCollection.ToArray()));                       

nsm.CreateQueue(currentQueueDescription);
```

Let's say I create 3 queues:

```
MyQueueOne
KeyName = MyListenManageSendKeyName11111111111111111111111111111111
KeyValue = abc1230000000000000000000000000000000000000

(code not shown, but same idea as the above)

MyQueueTwo
KeyName = MyListenManageSendKeyName22222222222222222222222222222222
KeyValue = def4560000000000000000000000000000000000000

MyQueueThree
KeyName = MyListenManageSendKeyName33333333333333333333333333333333
KeyValue = ghi7890000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Later on, I call code to GetAllQueues.

Like the below.  Note that I am using the shared-key-access , that originally was made for MyQueueOne.

```
string currentKeyName = "MyListenManageSendKeyName11111111111111111111111111111111";
string currentKeyValue = "abc1230000000000000000000000000000000000000"; 

ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbcsb = /* not shown */

TokenProvider tp = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(currentKeyName, currentKeyValue);

NamespaceManager nsm = new NamespaceManager(sbcsb.GetAbsoluteManagementEndpoints(), tp);

IEnumerable<QueueDescription> allQueues = nsm.GetQueues();
```

When I call the .GetAllQueues() methods, I get back

```
MyQueueOne
MyQueueTwo
MyQueueThree
```

is this expected behavior?

In my limited view, that specific key would only bring back MyQueueOne.

Is there anything I can do to only get back the queues that "fall under" the specific SharedAccessAuthorizationRule?

Answer (score 1):

> is this expected behavior?In my limited view, that specific key would only bring back MyQueueOne

No,If we use MyQueueOne shared key access to get the queue list, then will get the 401 error. And I am sure that if we want to list queues we need to use the default **RootManageSharedAccessKey**. And I also test it with your code and get the 401 error when try to `GetAllQueues`.

[image]

If I used the **RootManageSharedAccessKey** then could the result as you mentioned.

[image]

> Is there anything I can do to only get back the queues that "fall under" the specific SharedAccessAuthorizationRule?

If want to get the sepcific SharedAccessAuthorizationRule, we need to use **RootMangeSharedAccesskey** to generate `TokenProvider` then filter the result we wanted, the following is my test code and result.

```
TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "xxxxxx");
IEnumerable<QueueDescription> allQueues = nsm.GetQueues().Where(queue=>queue.Authorization.Count(auth => auth.KeyName.Equals(currentKeyName))>0);
```

[image]

Comment: Ok.  Even though I am using the shared-key-name/value to access, i'm not getting the exception.  However, I am "logged in" as the user who is in the group of Manage-Users.  I need to work from that angle (aka, remove myself as a Manage-User or get a different login so I'm solely relying on the shared-key authentication/authorization.

Comment: Are you using On-Premise or Azure?  I'm still not getting the exception when I'm logged in as another account and using shared-key-name-and-value.  My SB is on the same machine as I am running the code. (Dev Setup).

Comment: I tested it with azure servicebus.

Comment: Ok....as of yesterday, I'm getting different behavior with On Premise.  The .GetQueues() does not fail for me.  I'm still trying to rule out possibilities.  Today I'm installing On Premise SB on a different machine, just to rule out some "I'm an Admin on my own machine" voodoo, even though I'm always getting the TokenProvider with the shared-access-key(name/value).